# How to handle U-SQL error if the Table does not exist

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

How to handle U-SQL error (E_CSC_USER_DDLENTITYOFNEITHERTYPEEXISTS) if the table not exists.

How to use IF object_id('table1') Is not null in U-SQL?

T-SQL example:
if object_id('table1') Is not null
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store1
UNION ALL
if object_id('table2') is not null
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store2
UNION ALL
if object_id('table3') is not null
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store3

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question so it is clear what you would like to accomplish? As is, the question is a mixture of questions and statements with no formatting and a link...

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the confusion. I have rephrase the question above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

U-SQL currently offers `FILE.EXISTS` and `PARTITION.EXISTS` but not `TABLE.EXISTS`.

I added it to our backlog. Please file a feature request (or upvote an existing one if present) at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Current workarounds would be to code gen the script based on the table name using the `usql.tables` catalog view and then execute the code generated script, or keep the tables existing, just have them empty if they are not "existing".